# Spinner failing to populate in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hoping someone can help me on this.  For some reason that escapes me the spinner in the UI is not populating with any data.  I've searched high and low and tried a myriad of fixes after 8 hours of reading Stack Overflow questions and answers but no luck.  The toasted return data from the server is coming back fine but that data is not being forwarded into the spinner.

Im not getting any compile time or run time errors, so either Im not processing the JSON correctly, or Im overriding the content assigned to the spinner somewhere, not sure.

The code for the query is

```
<?php

include 'Dbconf.php';

 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 // Get list of current events
 //$qry = "SELECT EventID,EventName,EventDate FROM skid_event WHERE IsOpen ='1'";
 $qry = "SELECT EventID,EventName,EventDate FROM skid_event";
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$qry);

 if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$qry))
    {
      $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if ($rowcount > 0)
      {
            $rows = array();
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $rows[] = $r;
      }
      print json_encode($rows);


          //$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          //echo json_encode($row);
          mysqli_free_result($result);
          mysqli_close($con);
          exit();
      }
      else
      {
          echo "Fail";
      }
    }       
    else
    {    
        echo 'Failed'; 
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Which produces the following formatted JSON result, which is what I expect

[{"EventID":"1","EventName":"Burnout King","EventDate":"2017-04-14"},{"EventID":"2","EventName":"Gazzanats WA","EventDate":"2018-02-23"}]

The above is as I see it when I toast the server response in the app.

The fragment code looks like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;    
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindEventFragment extends Fragment{

    public static final String TAG = "FindEventFragment";
    private VolleyHelper mInstance;
    private ArrayList<String> eventList;
    private JSONArray result;
    private Spinner eventNameSpinner;
    private TextView eventDate;         
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;    
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;    
    public FindEventFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static FindEventFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FindEventFragment fragment = new FindEventFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue from VolleyHelper
        mInstance = VolleyHelper.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        // API
        connectApi();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop () {
        super.onStop();
        if (mInstance.getRequestQueue() != null) {
            mInstance.getRequestQueue().cancelAll(TAG);
        }
    }

    private void connectApi() {
        String url = "http://gblakes.ddns.net/get_events.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {                               
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            j = new JSONObject(ServerResponse);
                            result = j.getJSONArray("EventName");
                            eventDetails(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        if (mInstance != null) {
            // Add a request to your RequestQueue.
            mInstance.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            // Start the queue
            mInstance.getRequestQueue().start();
        }
    }

    private void eventDetails(JSONArray j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
                eventList.add(json.getString("EventName"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
        /**check this it could be wrong since Im trying to set an adapter that contains no data yet*/
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, eventList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        eventNameSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        eventNameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Setting the value to textview for a selected item
                eventDate.setText(getEventDate(position));
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                eventDate.setText("test me");
            }
        });
        // arrayList.add(0,"Select Event");
        //eventNameSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, eventList));
    }

    private String getEventID(int position) {
        String eventID = "";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            //Fetching name from that object
            eventID = json.getString("EventID");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return eventID;
    }

    private String getEventDate(int position){
        String eventDate="";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            eventDate = json.getString("EventDate");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return eventDate;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_event,container,false);
        eventNameSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinEventPicker);
        eventNameSpinner = new Spinner(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        eventDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textEventDate);
        eventDate.setText("test me");
        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

And the fragment xml looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/textEventName">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinEventPicker"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textEventDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinEventPicker"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If anyone can point out what Im doing wrong and a possible suggested fix that would be fantastic.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be instantiating your Spinner twice, first (the right way) referencing to the layout and the second time creating a totally new Spinner object.

```
eventNameSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinEventPicker);
eventNameSpinner = new Spinner(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

I believe if you removed the 2nd line of these two lines of code (found in onCreateView) it should work.

**EDIT:**

It seems there also need to be some changes with the handling of the JSON. First of all you need to change the use of the ServerResponse String.

```
try {
    result = new JSONArray(ServerResponse);
    eventDetails(result);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you need to change the way you access the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
        eventList.add(json.getString("EventName") + json.getString("EventDate");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

This should probably work.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I removed the second instantiation but still no luck, the same behavior persists.  I'll try and pull the values out of the JSONArray to make sure they are getting that far too

Comment: @gwunta You could check the values of eventList before you put them in the adapter (I'm curious what's inside it), also you could maybe do something with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after the list is filled

Comment: I tried to Toast the contents of eventList(0) with no result.  Now I'm wondering if my JSONArray to JSON Object code is non nonsensical

Comment: @gwunta what is the exact JSON you're getting from PHP?

Comment: exactly as I've posted it.  I've got a very small set of test data so the query only returns one line at this stage.....The output from the PHP is literally {"EventID":"1","EventName":"Burnout King","EventDate":"2017-04-14"}

Comment: @gwunta I see the problem, this is 1 JSONObject with multiple strings, not a JSONArray

Comment: not sure what you mean or how I go about correcting that.  Are you saying I should be working exclusively wit JSONObject rather than JSONObject and JSONArray?

Comment: @gwunta I'll edit my answer in a moment, but first I need to know what you want to display in your spinner, since this is one object with 3 parameters. Do you want this as one object with all parameters on one line or something  else?

Comment: @gwunta I believe you want a list of the eventnames looking at the code (you are aware that the PHP just contains one event right?)

Comment: So ideally the spinner will show data associated with EventName and EventDate, but I'll need the EventID so I can pas it back from the fragement for use elsewhere in the app.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The PHP will return more than one row when the referencing database is fully populated, but my PHP skills are poor, so I think I have that code wrong too

Comment: Your PHP should return an array if done correctly (you can see that in JSON if the JSON contains square brackets (that's the indicator for an array)). If you get that to work you still need to make a few changes to make it work, but you would be a lot closer. I can't really help since I lack skill in PHP.

Comment: I have updated the PHP which I believe to be working correctly now and updated my question to reflect the correct PHP and output

Comment: If you give the updated output, I'll give you the rest of the info you need

Comment: the updated output is literally (noting square brackets in the output now indicating an array)... [{"EventID":"1","EventName":"Burnout King","EventDate":"2017-04-14"},{"EventID":"2","EventName":"Gazzanats WA","EventDate":"2018-02-23"}]

Comment: @gwunta [] are square brackets, so this is a lot better, I'll edit my answer in a moment

Comment: @gwunta could you check the answer, I think this should do it.

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting a NPE with the following message:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference.  The offending line of code is eventList.add(json.getString("EventName") + json.getString("EventDate")); in the try catch when accessing the JSONObject as per your answer.  Could it be because the ArrayList is not initialized at the very top of the class?

Comment: @gwunta I think you forgot to initialize the eventList (eventList = new ArrayList();)

Comment: SUCCESS!!  Thank you so so much for your help, I've been working on this fragment for over 12 hours.  Thank you again!

Comment: @gwunta No problem, glad to help